# Maven dependency tree for parent pom with multiple profiles

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I am having a nested multi module maven project as below.

[image]

The parent pom specifies the profiles to build various component.

Now I need to get the list of all dependencies of all component which I believe that I can get from dependency tree of eclipse ide. But it is not getting displayed. Is there any other way to get the list or I am trying a wrong thing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) along with a profile in the normal way.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Pjava8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent                                                             [pom]
[INFO] project-mod-1                                                      [pom]
[INFO] java8                                                              [jar]
[INFO] java7                                                              [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.greg:parent >---------------------------
[INFO] Building parent 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                       [1/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ parent ---
[INFO] com.greg:parent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< com.greg:project-mod-1 >-----------------------
[INFO] Building project-mod-1 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                [2/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ project-mod-1 ---
[INFO] com.greg:project-mod-1:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------< com.greg:java8 >---------------------------
[INFO] Building java8 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                        [3/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ java8 ---
[INFO] com.greg:java8:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------< com.greg:java7 >---------------------------
[INFO] Building java7 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                        [4/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ java7 ---
[INFO] com.greg:java7:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for parent 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  2.262 s]
[INFO] project-mod-1 ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.015 s]
[INFO] java8 .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.111 s]
[INFO] java7 .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.250 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.169 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-20T08:18:24Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It is showing separately for individual projects. I need the combined list of dependencies for all child modules. Isn't possible?

Comment: @Anitha.R it doesn't exist in a combined way, only for individual projects, 2 projects under the same parent could have different dependencies and versions. You can control the versions of each project at the parent level using [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).